# Name for HTTP Request+Response

Tags: http, naming, http-1.1

There's one thing I haven't found in [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) ("Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1") and that's a "canonical" name for a request/response pair. Is there such thing?

[4.1 Message Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.1):

> ```
> 4.1 Message Types
>
>    HTTP messages consist of requests from client to server and responses
>    from server to client.
>
>        HTTP-message   = Request | Response     ; HTTP/1.1 messages
> ```

Taking this as a template, which word would you put in the following sentence?

```
A single complete HTTP ... consists of one HTTP Request and one HTTP Response

    HTTP-... = Request Response
```

roundtrip? cycle?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The spec calls them "exchanges" (or "request/response exchanges").

Per [section 1.4, "Overall Operation"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-1.4):

> In HTTP/1.0, most implementations used a new connection for each request/response exchange. In HTTP/1.1, a connection may be used for one or more request/response exchanges […]

Comment: Though I like the term transaction, what I really was looking for was a more "authoritative" reference like ..um, yeah.. the rfc itself. Thanks.

Comment: I like "transaction" too but I guess maybe that implies some guarantees that aren't there... if the response can't be delivered, then the request won't be rolled back.

Comment: True again. Then "exchange" it is.

Comment: rollback is kind of database specific.  transaction is used in many non-database contexts.  but if the rfc says exchange, go with that.

Comment: Imo, an HTTP transaction could have more than one exchange. If there is a redirection, there would be 2 exchanges, both would be within the same transaction. Just a thought...

Comment: The analogous section of RFC 2616's replacement, [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-2.1), uses the same terminology: "A connection might be used for multiple request/response exchanges, as defined in Section 6.3."

Answer (score 10):

- RFC2616 calls it an *Exchange*.
- Wireshark and HTTPNetworkSniffer call it a *Request/Response*.
- Fiddler calls it a *Session*.
- Charles calls it a *Sequence*.
- HTTP Scoop calls it a *Conversation*.
- Other vocabulary includes: *Message*, *Transaction*, *Communication*.

I would go for `Exchange` or `RequestResponse`.

I also went to name it `Operation` in my code as I would queue Operations, flush Operations, pause or resume Operations.

Answer (score 1):

**Exchanges** is nice name, also we can use **Connection**, **Communication** or **session**

Comment: Connection is not a good word to use for Exchanges, since it has another meaning - the underlying channel on which the messages are sent.

Answer (score 0):

**Payload**

In my project, I needed a name so that I can differentiate between models (Database) and HTTP interaction objects, so I am using payload, like:

- ProductPayload, ProductModel
- CartPayload, CartModel
- OrderPayload, OrderModel

Answer (score -1):

Transaction, yes, or "A singe HTTP Request consists of one HTTP Request message and one HTTP Response message."