# What is a request-response pair called?

Tags: http, naming

For example in HTTP you send a request and receive a response; is there a noun that describes that request-response pair?

I'd thought of "dialog" or "conversation" however those imply multiple request-response pairs, whereas I'm looking for a word that indicates exactly one.

The reason for asking is that I need to name an object which encapsulates the details of both, and `RequestResponse` seems fairly lame.

Comment: @bbrown - Hmm yes looks like it is. I didn't find that using either Google or the built-in search though :-(

Comment: No problem. It's just the first related article right over there...

Comment: @bbrown - Unfortunately that isn't shown until *after* you ask the question. It didn't appear in the "similar questions" list.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

How about "exchange"?

Comment: According to this previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325346/name-for-http-requestresponse), that's what the spec uses.

Answer (score 54):

- RFC2616 calls it an *Exchange*.
- Wireshark and HTTPNetworkSniffer call it a *Request/Response*.
- Fiddler calls it a *Session*.
- Charles calls it a *Sequence*.
- HTTP Scoop calls it a *Conversation*.
- Other vocabulary includes: *Message*, *Transaction*, *Communication*.

I would go for `Exchange` or `RequestResponse`.

I also went to name it `Operation` in my code as I would queue Operations, flush Operations, pause or resume Operations.

Comment: Really, a good choice, although RFC2616 refers to the word *exchange* merely twice.

Comment: Any chance you might copy/paste this answer?  The duplicate question has an accepted answer that is in my opinion significantly less thorough.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325346/name-for-http-requestresponse

Comment: @Jonathan done. Note that all this content being CC-By-SA, you could have copied it with attribution. :)

Answer (score 17):

`RequestResponsePair` sounds like it does exactly what it says. And that's invaluable, I find.

Answer (score 9):

Interaction

Comment: Right my idea, maybe we can give it an abbreviation: **ixn**, such a unique word.

Comment: @JimmChen i9n; about half of an i18n

Answer (score 8):

I'd use Message or Transaction

Comment: [TsSkTo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2660924/tsskto) [points out](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/125302/23199) that this can get confusing when you are working with but not currently talking about databases. [EricLaw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039513/what-is-a-request-response-pair-called#comment850282_1039589) points out that http traffic is not transactional. Regarding message, I think it's too loose concerning the count and direction of messages (it may consist of a pair but also can be just a single message).

Answer (score 4):

`Transceival` or `ServiceCall` might work.

Answer (score 4):

`HttpRoundTrip` - inspired by Jeff Atwood in [this blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000263.html)

Comment: That link is dead, unfortunately. I believe this is the post you meant: https://blog.codinghorror.com/aspnet-ntlm-authentication-is-it-worth-it/

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) calls it a ***Session***.

Comment: Session works pretty well, but it has the minor downside that some may assume that it has something to do with "session cookies" or related technologies.

Transaction seems like a fine name, except that Transaction implies that HTTP traffic is somehow transactional (with rollback, etc) which it's not.

Comment: i do't know what the OP's usage will be. But i use Fiddler quite a bit, and i've never had any problem with the term "session". In fact, it was so transparent (since it's just a term for that request-response pair) that had to load Fiddler to see what they called it, if anything.

Comment: Hey, wait a minute....Eric Lawrence...Fiddler

Comment: With the benefit of hindsight, I'd use `Exchange` if I were building Fiddler again.

Answer (score 1):

OpenRasta used "communication" for the request/response couple.

Comment: Can you specify what OR means?

Comment: Done, also put it in past tense as that fx is not relevant 5 years on.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case I consider calling it a `Connection`. When you send a HTTP request, you're basically establishing a connection with some endpoint.

At least one reason why I dislike it is that similar to `Session`, one can assume there is some activity at the moment happening, which may or may not be true.

Background: I need to log all interactions with third-party service.

P.S. IMHO, `Exchange` is the best among others. It sounds more abstract.

Answer (score 0):

What about `ServiceConversation`

Answer (score -1):

what about `RequestResponseContext`?

Comment: Every abstraction is a paradigm!

Comment: I read that sentence much differently.  "Request/response" modifies "paradigm", they are not synonyms.

Comment: Is it just me or didn't this answer get changed substantially from when it was first entered?