# What is the restTemplate.exchange() method for?

Tags: rest, resttemplate

Actually what does the `restTemplate.exchange()` method do?

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/getphoto", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getPhoto(@RequestParam("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {

    logger.debug("Retrieve photo with id: " + id);

    // Prepare acceptable media type
    List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);

    // Prepare header
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    // Send the request as GET
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = 
        restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:7070/spring-rest-provider/krams/person/{id}", 
                              HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class, id);

    // Display the image
    Writer.write(response, result.getBody());
}
```

Answer (score 28):

The [method documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) is pretty straightforward:

> Execute the HTTP method to the given URI template, writing the given request entity to the request, and returns the response as [`ResponseEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html).
>
> URI Template variables are expanded using the given URI variables, if any.

---

Consider the following code extracted from your own question:

```java
ResponseEntity<byte[]> result = 
    restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:7070/spring-rest-provider/krams/person/{id}", 
                          HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class, id);
```

We have the following:

- A [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) request will be performed to the given URL sending the HTTP headers that are wrapped in the [`HttpEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html) instance.
- The given URL contains a template variable (`{id}`). It will be replaced with the value given in the last method parameter (`id`).
- The response entity will be returned​ as a `byte[]` wrapped into a [`ResponseEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) instance.

Comment: Is this method synchronous or asynchronous? Based on the description, it is synchronous. I was wondering how does it handle requests that return a Future from a server.

Comment: `RestTemplate` is synchronous. See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html).

Comment: Your explanation was quite helpful.  But OP is right, the original text is essentially circular reasoning.  It is only understandable by people who already understand it.  I ended up here because I'm trying to port a script that uses exchange(), and that documentation is hopeless.

Answer (score 16):

TL;DR: **Q:** [What is a request-response pair called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1039513/86967) **A:** An "*exchange*".

---

The term *exchange* is used, almost incidentally, in [the official technical documentation of HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) to refer to an HTTP request combined with the corresponding response.

However looking at the answers to the following questions, it is clear that while this may have represented a de facto standard for some people, many other were not aware of it, or hadn't adopted it.

- [What is a request-response pair called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1039513/86967)
- [Name for HTTP Request+Response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/325346/86967)

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) doesn't bother to mention the etymology of the name -- probably assuming that it's obvious.

Notice, however, that there are many different RestTemplate HTTP request methods listed and only a small fraction of them are named *exchange*.  The list is primarily made up of [*HTTP method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol&oldid=950155641#Request_methods)-specific names such as `delete`, `put`, `getForEntity`, `postForObject`, et cetera.  Technically speaking, all of these methods perform *exchanges* in the same sense, but the more focused convenience methods are limited to a specific subset of the possible exchange functionality and parameter+return types.

To put it simply, **the set of `exchange` functions are the most general/capable  methods provided by `RestTemplate`**, so you can use `exchange` when none of the other methods provides a complete enough parameter set to meet your needs.

For example:

- [Sending GET request with Authentication headers using restTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21101250/86967), in which the OP has noticed that *"...the only way to send Headers such as accept and Authorization is by using the exchange method..."*

Answer (score 4):

The more generic exchange API requires a HttpMethod parameter and a request object for completeness. Compare:

```
ResponseEntity<Foo> response = 
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Foo.class);

ResponseEntity<Foo> response = 
restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Foo.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

The exchange method executes the HTTP method against the specified URI template, passing in the parameters for replacement. In this case it gets an image for a person entity for its Id parameter and returns the byte array for it.